# Issues in running java two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java, Now i am learning arrays,

This is example program:

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] twodim = new int[][] { {1,2,4,4}, {2,4,5,5,4,3,3} };
        int d1 = twodim.length;
        int d2 = twodim[1].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < d1; i++){
            for (int j = 0;j < d2; j++){
        System.out.println(twodim[i][j]);
            }}
    }

}
```

My output:

```
4
4
```

This is incorrect, please guide me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Is the length of the first inner array the same as the second inner array? I don't think so, but your code assumes that.

Comment: @forgivenson: That prints all the values right?.. 1 2 4 4 2 4 5 5 4 3 3

Comment: The length of two inner array is different @ZouZou

Comment: @selva So why are you doing `int d2 = twodim[1].length;`?

Comment: @ZouZou: That is length of second inner array..

Comment: @selva I don't get it. You know that the length of both arrays are not the same. What happens when you try to print the elements of the first inner array? How many iterations will the inner loop do? Do you think it's correct to iterate `twodim[1].length;` times for the first inner array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you included doesn't output what you said it does. Its output is:

> 1
>   2
>   4
>   4

And then it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Here is what your `d1` and `d2` variables are set to:

```
int d1 = twodim.length;
// d1 = 2, the length of the outer array
int d2 = twodim[1].length;
// d2 = 7, the length of the second inner array, [2,4,5,5,4,3,3]
```

So, the outer loop will loop twice, which is what you want.

However, the inner loop will always loop 7 times, since that is what `d2` equals. This results in printing out each of the numbers in the first inner array, 1, 2, 4, and 4, and then when it tries to access the 5th number, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs, since there is no 5th number in the first inner array.

Instead, you should have the second loop only loop through the contents of each array, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < twodim.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < twodim[i].length; j++) {
        // note that twodim[i].length is the length of the array that you are currently looping through
        System.out.println(twodim[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The output from this is:

> 1
>   2
>   4
>   4
>   2
>   4
>   5
>   5
>   4
>   3
>   3

Comment: I just confused, How can i understand length of these two arrays, can you please explain?

Comment: The length of an array is the number of items in the array. So, you have your outer array, `twodim`, which contains two inner arrays. So, its length is 2. The inner arrays have different lengths. The first one, at index 0 of the outer array, contains 4 integers (1,2,4,4), giving it a length of 4. The second inner array, at index 1, contains 7 integers (2,4,5,5,4,3,3), giving it a length of 7.

Comment: Thanks @forgivenson, and why we add     for(int j = 0; j < twodim[i].length; j++) for second inner array, i mean twodim[i].length?

Comment: Is  possibilities to print two dimensional array without using their length?

Comment: The reason for using `twodim[i].length` for the inner loop is to get the length of the current array. So, when `i = 0`, that length will be 4 (for the first inner array), and when `i = 1`, that length will be 7 (for the second inner array).

Comment: Is possibilities to print two dimensional array without using their length?

Comment: Nope. If you don't use their length, then you won't know when to stop loop through them, and you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you have further bugs/questions, you can always create new questions here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate, your loop parameters were wrong

basically, its a two dimensional array. the first loop checks the outer array length and the second loop checks length of each individual array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < twodim.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j < twodim[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(twodim[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @selva try to recompile the code and make sure ur compiling the right file. I just ran the code and got the expected results

Comment: may i know your output?

Answer (score 0):

Put the second dimension into the first loop:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] twodim = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 4, 4 }, { 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3 } };
        int d1 = twodim.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < d1; i++)
        {
            int d2 = twodim[i].length;
            for (int j = 0; j < d2; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(twodim[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why do you have **UnknownHostException** exception

Comment: sorry i can't understand what is throws UnknownHostException?.. I m new java, can you please explain me?

Comment: Hey removed the exception. I copied the code above and forgot to remove that. It's not necessary at all :) Sorry for that. Edited the answer.

Comment: May i know, what is my mistake?.. @JoeInner

Comment: The second dimension `d2` must be calculated dynamically within the loop, because embedded arrays may have a different size. `int d2 = twodim[1].length` calculates the length of the embedded array `{ 1, 2, 4, 4 }`, which is 4. The second array is `{ 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3 }`is 7. The variable d2 is never updated in your code.

Comment: @JoeInner: when i write int d1 = twodim[0].length; and d2 = twodim[1].length; I got the length of these two arrays..but you told length of first array is 4..

Comment: @joe: why we add for second inner array,             int d2 = twodim[i].length;?

Comment: because then the size of the second dimension is obtained dynamically

Answer (score -1):

Your code throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when i=0 and j=4.

This is because your arrays are not the same length as each other.